# Properly set defaults for gradle properties

Tags: properties, groovy, gradle

Having the following in `build.gradle`:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "$repoUrl") {
                authentication(userName: "$repoUser", password: "$repoPassword")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how can I make `$repoUrl` have a default value `file://$buildDir/repo`?

I tried to put `repoUrl=file://$buildDir/repo` in `gradle.properties`, but it doesn't work as I expected, as it seems that `$repoUrl` is not evaluated recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is because `repoUrl=file://$buildDir/repo` is treated as plain string, without `buildDir` substitution.

If may try this:

`repository(url: repoUrl.replace('$buildDir', "$buildDir")) {`

Or something like this:

```
// run as 'gradle build -PreportUrl=blabla'
def repoUrl = "file://$buildDir/repo"
if (binding.variables.containsKey('repoUrl ')) {
 repoUrl = binding.variables.get('repoUrl ')
}
```

Comment: Typo: `...replace('$buildDir', "$buildDir")...`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference Gradle properties like `project.buildDir` from properties files. Properties files are very limited, and in general, I'd recommend to keep all information in Gradle build scripts. You can have any number of build scripts, and include them with `apply from: "path/to/script"` in other scripts.

Comment: One of my Wow!s about gradle was that `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` has precedence over `<project>/gradle.properties`, for I insist on gradle.properties :)

Comment: Is there a way to specify a default value for a property inside a `build.gradle` and override it in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`?

Comment: Only with two properties and some logic in the build script. (Properties files are evaluated before build scripts.)